Restoring hashed filenames from Juiced (2005) DATs
Where is the memory address for the hash function from Juiced PC executable to restore hashed filenames?

Addresses are usually binary specific. I am not sure if "Juiced 2005" is specific enough for someone to know which exact executable version you use. Otherwise you can try to find it out yourself using Ghidra or a similar reverse engineering tool.
